# java.net.socket implementation

Tags: java, sockets, io

On linux, I assume that Java sockets end up calling the glibc sockets.

How does the interaction between these two layers happen? Is it akin to a JNI call or is there some special faster way of accessing glibc functions from Java?

Thanks!

Comment: What implementation of the Java API are you using? By "*glibc sockets*", do you mean POSIX or BSD sockets?

Comment: I mean POSIX sockets. I have not yet settled on which JDK to use, understanding the above for different JDKs will help in the decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sockets are implemented by the kernel, and the system call function wrappers are provided by whatever C library the JVM implementors happen to be using. Java calls the C library via JNI, the C library calls the kernel via a system-call software interrupt. There is no conceptual difference in this process between JDKs, although implementation details may vary.

> glibc sockets

There is really no such thing. Socket functions are system calls. All that glibc does is provide the C wrapper.